# Angularjs highlighting multiple options with given array of options in multi select form component

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an array of selected options and i need to highlight these array of options in select component among all available options..

Comment: you want that options of select are from the array??

Comment: no , i have previously registered user selected options and i have to highlight them in dropdown menu when he wants to edit his profile.. simply its like passing array to ng-selected in select component..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard behavior already highlights the selected options. Example below. In the example two options are selected by default.

```js
angular
  .module('exampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ExampleController);

function ExampleController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.options = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'Option A'
  }, {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Option B'
  }, {
    id: '3',
    name: 'Option C'
  }];
  vm.selectedOptionNames = ['Option B', 'Option C'];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='exampleApp'>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="multipleSelect">Make a choice:</label>
    <select name="multipleSelect" id="multipleSelect" ng-options="option.name as option.name for option in vm.options" ng-model="vm.selectedOptionNames" multiple>
    </select>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks scottl , here is one issue in my application only one option is highlighting multiple options are not highlighting even i did same as you. And also i tried by putting isOptionSelected always true then also only one option is highlighting ..